# Recovering User After An Upgrade

Tags: upgrade, permissions, login, users

So I recently did an upgrade from 14.04 to 16.04.5 ( planning to continue to 18.04.1 ) and when I logged in to what I thought was my user I saw that all my files weren't there.  At first I thought that it had somehow formatted the drive during the upgrade, but now I see that what actually happened is that it created a new admin user, with a login two letters shorter than my previous login, but the same password.  The previous user data is still in the home directory, just not accessible, except via sudo.

So for example, let's say before my user was catmando.  So now the admin login and only user on the system is catman, with the same password as catmando.  catman's home directory is empyt except for default files, and catmando's files are still in the home directory, but the user catmando isn't listed in the user accounts app, only catman is listed there.

So how can I restore catmando as the main admin login of the system?

Comment: Not sure but a guess that what if you change your home directory to `/home/catmando` in `/etc/passwd` for this new user.

Comment: Don't bother restoring anything until your migration to 18.04 is complete.